# Virtualbox: How to install guest additions on a Windows10 guest on Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running a Windows 10 guest on an Ubuntu 18.04 host.

Within the Windows 10 guest, browsers are able to connect to the internet.

When I go to 'Devices' -> 'Insert guest addition CD image', a dialogue pops up immediately.

The dialogue window says:

'Network Operations Manager', 'Looking for VirtualBox Guest Additions'...

"The network operation failed with the following error: During network request: unkown reason".

How do I install the guest additions?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Download the ISO file yourself. For 6.0.14, the url is

```
wget https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.14/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.14.iso
```

Then Devices --> Optical Drives --> Choose Disk Image and point the dialog to where you downloaded the ISO file. If autorun is disabled, open the windows  file explorer and go to the CD's contents and double click the executable.